# How to implement methods for multiple new pushpins in windows store app using Bing maps

Tags: c#, windows-8, bing-maps, windows-store-apps, pushpin

I'm making a Windows Store app using C# and need a bit of help with a method for when a pushpin on a map is tapped.
So far I create a Pushpin called currentPin that I create in the XAML code. I also make a reference for the Tapped event here called pushpin_Tapped.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <bm:Map x:Name="MyMap" Credentials="{StaticResource BingMapsApiKey}" Holding="map_Held">

            <bm:Map.Children>
                <bm:Pushpin x:Name="pin" Tapped="pushpinTapped">

                </bm:Pushpin>
            </bm:Map.Children>
        </bm:Map>
    </Grid>
```

I then place the currentPin on my current location in the OnNavigatedTo method in the MainPage.xaml.cs code. I also create the method for when this pushpin is tapped. In this method I show a dialog box for when the currentPin is tapped.

```
private async void pushpinTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {

                var x = MapLayer.GetPosition(pin);
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("You are here " + x.Latitude + " " + x.Longitude);
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
```

I then have a method that place a new pushpin on a location when the map is held by the user, code below:

```
private void map_Held(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)        
{            
    Debug.WriteLine("You held at" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "" + e.GetPosition(MyMap));            
    var pos = e.GetPosition(MyMap);            
    Location location;            
    MyMap.TryPixelToLocation(pos, out location);                          
    Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();            
    MyMap.Children.Add(pin);                        
    MapLayer.SetPosition(pin, location);                       
}
```

I know it's probably staring me in the face but I'm blanking on how to get a message box or dialog box or anything to happen when each of these new pins is tapped. Could anyone shed some light please?
Thanks,
Aimee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Map_Held, add the handler for the tapped event...

```
private void map_Held(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)        
{            
    Debug.WriteLine("You held at" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "" + e.GetPosition(MyMap));            
    var pos = e.GetPosition(MyMap);            
    Location location;            
    MyMap.TryPixelToLocation(pos, out location);                          
    Pushpin newpin = new Pushpin();            
    newpin.Tapped += pushpin_Tapped;
    MyMap.Children.Add(newpin);                        
    MapLayer.SetPosition(newpin, location);                       
}
```

and in your tapped event handler, change the reference to your pin from `pin` to the following.

```
private async void pushpinTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PushPin tappedpin = sender as PushPin;  // gets the pin that was tapped
    if(null == tappedpin) return;           // null check to prevent bad stuff if it wasn't a pin.
    var x = MapLayer.GetPosition(tappedpin);
    MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("You are here " + x.Latitude + " " + x.Longitude);
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void map_Held(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)        
{            
    Debug.WriteLine("You held at" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "" + e.GetPosition(MyMap));            
    var pos = e.GetPosition(MyMap);            
    Location location;            
    MyMap.TryPixelToLocation(pos, out location);                          
    Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
    pin.Tapped += pushpinTapped;  // <<<<<<=====LOOK AT THIS
    MyMap.Children.Add(pin);                        
    MapLayer.SetPosition(pin, location);                       
}
```